# (NODE MODULES IN VUEJS)This relative module was not found?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

[This is image of traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sru0u.png)

**I got this trace back, I do not get this error until I pull new code from github, but I cannot detect what module is not imported**

```
* ./assets in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/JobDetailPrint.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
No type errors found
Version: typescript 3.9.7
Time: 7371ms
^C
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is going to be extremely difficult to troubleshoot on StackOverflow. I assume you ran `npm install` after pulling the new code?

Comment: The error indicates an `./assets` reference in `./src/components/JobDetailPrint.vue?vue&type=script`, so check that component's `<script>` for `./assets`. Unless you actually have `./src/components/assets`, that path isn't valid from that component.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when I rename file or folders of the components. Make sure you have change all the reference of the files. This link may help: [enter link description here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3784)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30675987)